# serializing to JSON that would retain hebrew charcters

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I have the following use case:

from data I produce a json with data, part of it hebrew words.
for example:

```
import json
j = {}
city =u'חיפה' #native unicode
j['results']= []
j['results'].append({'city':city}) #Also tried to city.encode('utf-8') and other encodings
```

In order to produce a json file that doubles as my app db (a micro geoapp) and as a file my users can edit and fix data directly I use the json lib and:

```
to_save = json.dumps(j)
with open('test.json','wb') as f: #also tried with w instead of wb flag.
   f.write(to_save)
   f.close()
```

The problem is I get a unicode decoded json with u'חיפה' represented for example as:
u'\u05d7\u05d9\u05e4\u05d4'

most of the script and app don't have any problem reading the Unicodestring but my USERS have one!, and since contributing to the opensource project they need to edit the JSON directly, they can't figure out the Hebrew text.

so, THE QUESTION: how should I write the json while opening it in another editor would show Hebrew characters?

I'm not sure this is solvable because I suspect JSON is unicode all the way and I can't use asccii in it, but not sure about that.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `ensure_ascii=False` argument.

```
>>> import json
>>> city = u'חיפה'
>>> print(json.dumps(city))
"\u05d7\u05d9\u05e4\u05d4"
>>> print(json.dumps(city, ensure_ascii=False))
"חיפה"
```

According to [`json.dump` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump):

> If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the
>   output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences, and the result is a str
>   instance consisting of ASCII characters only. If ensure_ascii is
>   False, some chunks written to fp may be unicode instances. This
>   usually happens because the input contains unicode strings or the
>   encoding parameter is used. Unless fp.write() explicitly understands
>   unicode (as in codecs.getwriter()) this is likely to cause an error.

Your code should read as follow:

```
import json
j = {'results': [u'חיפה']}
to_save = json.dumps(j, ensure_ascii=False)
with open('test.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(to_save.encode('utf-8'))
```

or

```
import codecs
import json
j = {'results': [u'חיפה']}
to_save = json.dumps(j, ensure_ascii=False)
with codecs.open('test.json', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(to_save)
```

or

```
import codecs
import json
j = {'results': [u'חיפה']}
with codecs.open('test.json', 'wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(j, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Just a note: According to [JSON docs](http://www.json.org/) a value can contain any Unicode characters (except `"` , `\ ` and control chars) _or_ escaped ones (like `\u05d7`). So both versions of `json.dump` produce valid JSON.

Comment: @falsetru what was biting me was the ```fp.write()```, which sent me to a whole goose chase after the correct ```json.dumps``` config (since I already tried the one you suggested) - the ```codecs.write()``` tip was the missing part for me. notice you should ```codecs.open('file.json','wb',encoding='utf-8')``` for this to work.

Comment: @falsetru notice you don't need the ```to_save``` line now, your version is more elegant

Comment: @alonisser, You are right. The last version does not need `to_save`. I edited that.